# Unhandled rejection: ChainErr("missing field `proof`")

Tags: rust, blockchain, smartcontracts, nearprotocol

I am running a local testnet with a single validator using docker. After deploying a smart contract written in Rust to the chain, I call one of the contract's methods from a webserver (also written in Rust). The call is made by building a SignedTransaction (from `near_primitives::transaction::*`), and broadcasting it to the network via JSON-RPC:

```rust
const NEAR_NODE: &'static str = "http://localhost:3030";

macro_rules! json_reqwest {
    ($req:expr => $client:ident) => {
        {
            let res = $client.post(NEAR_NODE)
                .json(&$req)
                .send()
                .await
                .map_err(|e| e.to_string())?
                .json::<Response>()
                .await
                .map_err(|e| e.to_string())?;
            serde_json::from_value(res.result.map_err(|e| e.message)?)
                .map_err(|e| e.to_string())?
        }
    };
}

async fn broadcast_tx(client: &Client, signed_tx: &mut SignedTransaction) -> Result<FinalExecutionOutcomeView, String> {
    signed_tx.init();
    println!("NEAR Tx hash: {}", signed_tx.get_hash());
    let tx = signed_tx.try_to_vec().map_err(|e| e.to_string())?;
    Ok(json_reqwest!(Message::request("broadcast_tx_commit".to_string(), Some(json!([to_base64(&tx)]))) => client))
}
```

This is the response from the network:

```
Unhandled rejection: ChainErr("missing field `proof`")
```

What does this error mean, and how can I address it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. We can't tell what library you are using or what version. Moreover, what's a "local testnet" or a "smart contract"? And what kind of server are you running?

Comment: The issue _probably_ comes from what you are putting in your `json!`: you're sending a list containing a single string, but I guess you probably should send an object with a `proof` field containing the string.

Comment: sorry for the lack of context or a reproducible example. This issue comes from working with https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore. I'm using v0.3.7 of near-bindgen, and the master branch of nearcore. Unfortunately reproducing this result involves quite a bit of setup, detailed here https://docs.nearprotocol.com/docs/local-setup/local-dev-node.

Comment: The server I am running is built using https://github.com/seanmonstar/warp. It is effectively a JSON-RPC server.

Comment: @kaiba42 is this still an issue with current near-rust-sdk 0.9.0+ and nearcore 1.0.0+?

Answer (score 0):

This problem existed in an old version of nearcore and should be solved in 1.0.0+.